# Creating GUI components dynamically in java

Tags: java, swing

So, we can create for example a button dynamically:

```
panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
validate();
```

But the question is, how do we make calls to those elements later? For example, how do I add an event listener to this button created above, like, 100 lines of code later?

Comment: You would need a variable for the button, just like you have for `panel`.

Comment: Store the JButton away somewhere (e.g. field variable) to access it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable for your JButton:

```
JButton jButton = new JButton("Button");
panel.add(jButton);
validate();
/*
 *
 *
100 lines of code 
 *
 */

// add an event listener
jButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent) -> {
            // do something
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always created my buttons before adding to the panel like so

```
   private JPanel buttonPanel() { //button panel method containting 
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
        addButton.setToolTipText("Add Customer Data");
        JButton editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        editButton.setToolTipText("Edit selected Customer");
        JButton deleteButton = new JButton ("Delete");
        deleteButton.setToolTipText("Delete selected Customer");

        addButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent) -> {
            doAddButton();
        });
        editButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent) -> {
            doEditButton();
        });
        deleteButton.addActionListener((ActionEvent) -> {
            doDeleteButton();
        });

        panel.add(addButton);
        panel.add(editButton);
        panel.add(deleteButton);

        return panel;
    }
```

Allows you do something like this later on.

```
    private void doAddButton() { //provides action for add button
    CustomerForm customerForm = new CustomerForm(this, "Add Customer", true);
    customerForm.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    customerForm.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Ok, the problem is, I don't know how many rows will be returned from the database query. Say, 23 results come from the query which means I need 23 buttons. Can I use array with size of 23 to store 23 separate buttons?

Comment: Arraylist maybe the way to go in that case.  I'm not all that familiar with setting an array for to create buttons with each increment though.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In order to bind event listeners or other functionality into the button, you'd need to store a reference to it in a variable. So, instead of

```
panel.add(new JButton("Button"));
```

You could initialize the button with

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("Button");
panel.add(myButton);
```

and then later in your code

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
         // do something
     } 
});
```

Comment: If you use an AbstractAction, then the first would be perfectly fine: `panel.add(new JButton(new ButtonAction()));`